# Simple application to convert character to ascii

Tags: vb.net, ascii

I'm trying to code a very simple program in vb.net to display the ASCII code for a specific character. I have a form with a textbox, button and a label, to use the input from the textbox to get the ascii for, and then display it in the label.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mydata As Char
    TextBox1.Text = mydata
    Dim toto As Short
    toto = Asc(mydata)
    Label1.Text = toto
End Sub

End Class
```

When I click the button I get `0` in the label instead of the correct ASCII, but when I filled the `asc()` method with a fixed character it worked fine.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

What is `mydata`? I think you want to remove:

```
TextBox1.Text = mydata
```

and change toto assignment to:

```
toto = Asc(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: I tried this already, and got this error:
Length of argument 'String' must be greater than zero.

Comment: You must first check to make sure there is a value in the TextBox. In programming, you do a lot of null checking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong way round:

```
TextBox1.Text = mydata
```

Should be

```
mydata = TextBox1.Text
```

However as Crowcoder has said, remove the use of the variable altogether

You can chop it right down to:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = Asc(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked when i changed it to:
mydata = TextBox1.Text
Thanks so much for you both.